# How can I use the cron?

Tags: php, linux, cron

How reload a php script every 1-5seconds in cron ? 
Would not it be better to use [System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/download) to reload the php script?
I have Debian System.

Comment: You can't do stuff every N seconds in cron. Minimum resolution is 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't really do this with cron, but instead you could write a script (either shell or php) that would loop forever and do something *every X seconds*.
- In addition, make a crontab entry that would run *every Y minutes* and launch that script (if it's still not running). You can do the latter using a pid file that your script creates (read the pid and check if there is a process with that id).

  This check can also be internal within the script - so that when the script is started more than once, it would check if another copy alrady running

Comment: I'm really new to linux
or when make will do a cron script sh
1 [TAB] * [TAB] * [TAB] * [TAB] * / root / command.sh
This is well-written?
and in script sh I will apply sleep(5)?
Nobody has written reviews for a daemon-system had someone with this contact?

Comment: * * * * * (5 asterisks) means every minute. i didn't use this system_daemon you mentioned, but writing an infinite loop in any language is really easy...